# How to test passport.js authenticate

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, passport.js

I wanted to test my passport.js authentication middleware:

```
passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
  if (err) return res.serverError(err)
  if (!user) return res.forbidden(info)
  req.user = user
  next()
})(req, res, next)
```

The middleware is working. But I don't know how to wait for the callback in my test. The test looks like this:

```
const token = JwtAuthService.issue({ id: 1, email: 'test@email.com' })
const req = httpMocks.createRequest({ headers: { authorization: `bearer ${token}` } })
const res = { forbidden: sinon.spy() }
const next = sinon.spy()

isAuthenticated(req, res, next);

(res.forbidden.called).should.be.false();
(next.calledOnce).should.be.true();
```

Since `passport.authenticate(...)` is no promise I cannot simply await the response. How can I wait for the callback of the `passport.authenticate(...)` function before testing if `res.forbidden` or `next` was called.

Comment: just replace stuff,, put your test in function and then call it in auth block, after you have authed `user`

Comment: @KresimirPendic If understood you right, you suggested to call the test within the passport.authenticate() callback. But I don't want my test to be part of the middleware.

Comment: @Lando-L did you ever figure out how to do this?  I'm in the same predicament.

Comment: @cag8f Unfortunately not. But I also haven't looked into it for a long time.